# How to add appendix label to appendices for report document class

Tags: labels, appendices

The following MWE works fine for the article class, but it doesn't work for the report class.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\section{title 1}
\section{title 2}

\begin{appendices}
\section{Some Notation}

\section{Some More Notation}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The top-level sectioning command for the `report` class is `\chapter`, not `\section`.